# VB6 to C#: Hash Sign For Converting to Double

Tags: c#, type-conversion, vb6-migration

I am currently converting a VB6 project to C#, and I have noticed that VB6 allowed you to add a `#` after an integer during a calculation to mark (and convert) it as a double.

Example:

```
If valueAsDeg >= (1# / 60#) Then Err.Raise - 1
```

Is there a ***similar*** way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the suffix "D", e.g. `1D`

> By default, a real numeric literal on the right-hand side of the
>   assignment operator is treated as double. However, if you want an
>   integer number to be treated as double, use the suffix d or D.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/678hzkk9(v=vs.110).aspx

```
double result = 1 / 60;
Console.WriteLine( result );
```

Output: 0

```
double result = 1D / 60D;
Console.WriteLine( result );
```

Output: 0.0166666666666667

Note that there are similar suffixes for `float` "F", `decimal` "M", and `long` "L", as well as support for [unsigned suffixes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx).

Comment: Awesome! Will give you the answer when it allows me.